# Change state and call the api in useEffect, But api called with previous state not with updated state

Tags: reactjs

**Change state and call the api in useEffect, But api called with previous state not with updated state.**
const Treades = () => {
const [trades, setTrades] = useState([]);

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Outdata is props
  setTrades(outdata.filters);

  // Method to get the list of trades
  getListOfTrades();
}, [trades]);

const getListOfTrades = async () => {
  let queryParams = {};

  queryParams["trades"] = trades;

  try {
    const { data: { data = [], meta: { pagination = {} } = {} } = {} } =
      await getTradeList(queryParams);

    setTradeList(tradeList.concat(data));

    setIsFilterPopup(false);
    setPagination(pagination);
  } catch ({ data: { error: { message = "" } = {} } = {} }) {
    JPFireMessages.fire("tostFrom:React", { type: "error", data: message });
  } finally {
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
};

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR** - pass the relevant state to your function:

```
const Treades = () => { 
  const [trades, setTrades] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Outdata is props
    setTrades(outdata.filters);

    // Method to get the list of trades
    getListOfTrades(outdata.filters);
  }, [trades]);

  const getListOfTrades = async (propsTrades) => {
    let queryParams = {};

    queryParams["trades"] = propsTrades;

    try {
      const { data: { data = [], meta: { pagination = {} } = {} } = {} } = await getTradeList(queryParams);

      setTradeList(tradeList.concat(data));

      setIsFilterPopup(false);
      setPagination(pagination);
    } catch ({ data: { error: { message = "" } = {} } = {} }) {
      JPFireMessages.fire("tostFrom:React", { type: "error", data: message });
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
};
```

**Explanation** - `useState` works in *asynchronous* way, so when you're accessing the state inside `getListOfTrades` you're actually accessing the previous state.

Notice that you might have a different problem in your `useEffect` callback - `trades` is in the dependency array and you're updating it with a call to `setTrades`. This eventually retriggers the `useEffect` callback once again, causing infinite loop. You might want to consider removing `trade` from the array - thus causing `useEffect` to act similar to `componentDidMount`, or rethink of your app logic to prevent this.

Comment: i know that, i want solution for state, i know my state create a infinite loop in useEffect can you tell how fix the issue of useState.